How can I rebase a series to a different base year?
I have three monthly data set for import prices.
First one --> Base year = 2003 (2003=100), data period: 2003 M1 - 2012 M12.
Second one --> Base year = 2010 (2010=100), data period: 2010 M1 - 2020 M12
Third one --> Base year = 2015 (2015 = 100), data period = 2013 M1 - 2024 M5.
I would like to create a data set coving all periods (between 2003 M1 and 2024 M5) with the same base year? How can I do this?

Are your prices series consistent (up to rounding)?  So for example is the proportional price change 2010 M1 to 2012 M12 the same for the first series and the second series, and is the proportional price change 2013 M1 to 2020 M12 the same for the second series and the third series?

No, these series are "unit value of import price index" which is used as a proxy for import price index for Turkey. Therefore, series are not consistent.
